# Publishing actions in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application and i did all the needed things to create an application while submit of the particular action, i get the error as follows

```
    {
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/samarulraj:cook?movie=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.yadhavan.com\u00252F&access_token=myaccesstoken&offset=25&limit=25"
   }
}
```

and while submitting i get as follows
[image]

Comment: BTW, are you sure you wanna `cook` that `movie`? FYI, you also have problem with `og:image` meta tag in that `movie` page (it's required tag and cannot be empty).

Comment: yes cook is my Action , and the movie is my object

Comment: _„User xy has cooked DIE HARD 4.0”_ – good luck getting _that_ combo approved by Facebook! Just out of curiosity, what published actions can we expect next from your app, _„User xz has watched a dish of indian food for 120 minutes (and had some popcorn while he was at it)”_ ...? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the error messages and do what they say you need to do:

- Implement publishing of an actions to OpenGraph in your application code, and publish at least one action. (Near the "Submit" link for Action in Application Settings, there is also "Get Code" link which show you basic information on requests needed for action publishing).
- Create aggregation that uses that Action and/or Objects that Action applied to.
- Submit your action to approval describing detailed steps to reproduce action publishing in your application.

You should (re?)read documentation on OpenGraph:

- [OpenGraph Application Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) (starting from step3 [Define Objects, Actions and Aggregations](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#define))
- [OpenGraph documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)
- [Key Concepts](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/)

Comment: i get this error,, i don't know how to do it Publish Actions
You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type. Review the documentation.

Provide Aggregation Sample Data
Aggregations were not properly set up for this Action Type. Please ensure that Aggregations are created and populated with sample data.

Comment: this was given as above attachment image

Comment: @SamArulRaj, I've read the error from the screenshot (it's really was better to place this text instead of screenshot in the question itself) before giving an answer. Anyway I've updated my answer and provided links to the documentation

Comment: @SamArulRaj, title on down-vote button says (citing): *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. 1. This is exactly what I think about question. 2. Down-vote in any way decrease chances to be answered. 3. You never know who made the downvote!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar data back from my requests. Make sure you are using "POST".  By default curl uses GET and so does the standard facebook api request (you have to pass 'post' as a param).  For curl I used the function:
// The submitted form data, encoded as query-string-style
// name-value pairs(name=value&name2=vale)

```
function myCurl($url, $params) {
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
return $response;
}
```

In my FB api requests I used:

```
var params = {};
params['app_namespace:object_name'] = 'http://<?php echo $CONFIG->HOST; ?>/find.php';
FB.api('/me/app_namespace:action_name', 'post', params, function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
    console.log(response);//remove this in production
} else {
    console.log(response);//remove this in production
}
});
```

Comment: Good spot, the OP's pasted result is clearly a GET request, not the response to a POST